# NaN.NaN.NaN values in IE8 for Ext JS grid date value

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a Grid with json Store and a DateField. Firefox ist working good, but its not working in Internet Explorer 8.

I define it like this:

```
function convert(v, rec) {
    var value;
    Ext.isEmpty(v) ? value = '' : value = v;
    return value;
}

fields : [                      
    {name: 'date1', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d', convert: convert},
    {name: 'date2', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d', convert: convert},
]
```

In Firefox it look good, but in Internet Explorer it is only `NaN.NaN.NaN`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a convert function. The whole point of specify a dateFormat is that you're telling the reader "My dates are coming from the server in this format, parse them and turn them into date objects".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line to more standard syntax:

```
value = Ext.isEmpty(v) ? '' : v;
```

Comment: If you add `alert(value);` before the return line what you see?

Comment: I can see the value as '2013-02-07' for the data having values and '' for null values

Comment: So it means some other code is failing. Can you find the code converting the value to numbers?

Comment: No. If i am not using the convert function, then its working good. but i need that function to handle null values.

Comment: The convert function is supposed to return a date object. By specifying your own custom convert method it will override the one that would be automatically created to handle the dateFormat config.

Comment: @Evan oh my... and no way to detect the original convert method and save it?

Comment: You can easily write your own convert method. Have a look at Ext.data.Types.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use isNaN function:
here goes an example:

function(value) {
        if (isNaN(value)){
       return ""; //any value you want
    }
    return value;
    },